# how to use redis geo radius command go lang

Tags: go, redis, geo, radius

I'm developing with Go lang and very new to it. I would like to use the redis GEORADIUS command and get back my results including the distance.

I have now used two packages radix.v2 and redigo to try and get results but had no joy. I have no issues using simple commands such as SET and GET.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: added code :-)

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "github.com/mediocregopher/radix.v2/redis"
  //"reflect"
  "encoding/json"
)

var (
  client *redis.Client
)

type Facility struct {
  Id string
  Dist string
}

func main() {
  client, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "192.168.99.100:6379")
  if err != nil {
    // handle err
  }

  surname, err := client.Cmd("GET", "surname").Str()
  if err != nil {
    // handle err
  }

  fmt.Println(surname)

  reply, _ := client.Cmd("GEORADIUS", "venues", 50, 0, 25, "mi", "WITHDIST", "ASC").Array()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  //fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(reply))
  //fmt.Println(reply)

  var facilities []Facility

  for _, results := range reply {
    facility, _ := results.Array()

    id, _ := facility[0].Str()
    dist, _ := facility[1].Str()

    facilities = append(facilities, Facility{
      Id: id,
      Dist: dist,
    })
  }

  //fmt.Println(facilities)

  resp, _ := json.Marshal(facilities)
  fmt.Fprintf(w, string(resp))    
}
```

Cheers
Stephen

Comment: Show the code that you tried.

Comment: I kept working at it and i'm getting closer but not sure if it is the best way to get the data I need.

Comment: What happens when your run this program? What's the expected output?

Comment: the repsonse:

mysurname
[]*redis.Resp

[Resp(Resp(Str "535") Resp(Str "24.4020")) Resp(Resp(Str "289") Resp(Str "24.8763")) Resp(Resp(Str "527") Resp(Str "24.9190"))]

Resp(Str "535")

Resp(Str "24.4020")

Resp(Str "289")

Resp(Str "24.8763")

Resp(Str "527")

Resp(Str "24.9190")

Comment: The command is returning what look like reasonable results. Edit your question to show what the program produces and how it's different from what you expect.

Comment: That must have been the correct response. I have updated my code above. Not sure if its the best way right now but it give me the result I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code in the redis package.

the file commands.go has all the signatures

a few signatures are below

GeoAdd(key string, geoLocation ...*GeoLocation) *IntCmd
GeoPos(key string, members ...string) *GeoPosCmd
GeoRadius(key string, longitude, latitude float64, query *GeoRadiusQuery) GeoRadiusByMember(key, member string, query *GeoRadiusQuery) 
GeoDist(key string, member1, member2, unit string) *FloatCmd

Comment: below is an actual example

res, err := client.GeoRadius("Sicily", 15, 37, &redis.GeoRadiusQuery{
         Radius:      200,
         Unit:        "km",
         WithGeoHash: false,
         WithCoord:   true,
         WithDist:    true,
         Count:       10,
         Sort:        "ASC",
       }).Result()